# Using lambda expression as function argument

Tags: c++

One of my class member function needs other member functions as arguments. I learnt that the member function pointer or lambda expression can pass the member function to another member function. I did this in my class declaration:

```
class A
{
public:
void run();

private:
double objfun1();
double objfun2();
.... // and other object function added here
template <typename Callable>
fun_caller(Callable obj_call);

};
```

When I need to pass different object functions to fun_caller in the public function A::run(), I first define the lambda expression:

```
void run()
{
... //some code blocks
auto obj_call = [this](){return objfun1();}; 
fun_caller(obj_call);
... // some code blocks
}
```

The compiler reports error.

```
error C2297: '->*': illegal, right operand has type 'Callable'
```

What's wrong with my lambda expression?
Thank you very much!!

Comment: `The compiler reports error.` _Which_ error?

Comment: You can store the lambda in a `std::function` and use `std::function` as the argument type.

Comment: error C2297: '->*': illegal, right operand has type 'Callable'

Comment: In the code above there's a semicolon missing behind the return statement in your lambda.

Comment: Yes, actually I can use std::function directly store the member function. But I want to know why this lambda expression cannot work?

Comment: There is no `->*` in the code you have shown.

Comment: God! I found very stupid bug in the fun_call(), it is more complex than what I showed here. I found I used -> it at one line. I wrote mindlessly.

Answer (score 3):

[This works:](https://godbolt.org/z/x6vGc5xWE)

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    void run();

private:
    double objfun1(){ return 1.; }
    double objfun2(){ return 2.; }

    template <typename Callable>
    void fun_caller(Callable obj_call){
        std::cout << "called: " << obj_call() << "\n";
    }
};

void A::run(){
    auto obj_call = [this](){return objfun1();}; 
    fun_caller(obj_call);
}

int main(){
    A obj;
    obj.run();
}
```

Comment: Thank you infinitezero!! I found I wrote a stupid bug in the fun_call(). Now this question could be closed.

Comment: @YS_Jin as a good practice, it's useful to write a Minimal Working Example. Not only can you post it here, often enough you can then find the mistake on your own :)